# BluetoothSocket.isConnected() isn't available on Android 2.3.4

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on a bluetooth app and just realised that BluetoothSocket.isConnected() was added in API Level 14 (Android 4.0) and isn't present in API Level 8.0 (Android 2.3.4)

The only way I can think of keeping tabs on this is through a boolean flag in the activity itself which is set to true if the connections succeeds. But from a hardware point of view, I don't think this is as reliable as isConnected(). Is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

PS: The app I'm working on needs to be compatible from Android 2.2 onwards.

EDIT: I'm using a boolean flag to keep track of it for now and it works fine. But would be happy to know if there's any other way to get connection status

Comment: Maybe `BluetoothSocket.getRemoteDevice()` would help? Connected if returns an instance of a `BluetoothDevice`, othewise not connected.

Comment: @shoerat: Thanks, however, `getRemoteDevice()` returns a `null` object if the socket was never connected but doesn't return a `null` object after `BluetoothSocket.close()`. Not as reliable as `BluetoothSocket.isConnected()`

Answer (score 1):

The isConnected() function in the latest version of android is just a field which returns one of the following constants.

SocketState.CLOSED
SocketState.INIT
SocketState.LISTENING
SocketState.CONNECTED

So it's operating in essentially the same way as your Boolean flag.